# How do I map an array and get the result as following by appending the previous and next value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, foreach

lets say I have an array of ID

```
id = [10,12,13,14,15]
```

I wish to map the id and get the following output as follow:

```
"id=10 OR id=12 OR id=13 or id=14 or id=15"
```

I tried the following but did not get the result as expected

```
let tempArray=  id.map((item, index)=>{
  return index  ? `id=${item} OR id=${item}`:""
})
```

Comment: You forgot the backticks around `id=${item} OR id=${item}`

Comment: @Kokodoko they were there, but it showed it as MarkDown formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map each value to the string `id=${value}` and then `join` the result with `" OR "`:

```js
const ids = [10,12,13,14,15];
const str = ids.map((value) => `id=${value}`).join(" OR ");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: thank you I tried this as well now, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
id.map(item => `id=${item}`).join(' OR ')
```

[image]